# How come 'much enough' isn't correct if 'big enough' is correct?

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-choice, word-usage, grammatical-number

I'm asking for my friend who is learning English. Although I'm a native speaker, I can't really explain it besides "it's not right".

Can someone explain why saying "much enough" isn't correct, while "big enough" is correct? Much and big are both adjectives.

Use case: "it's much enough, we don't need to order anything else."

Comment: I wouldn’t know how, but you could always ask why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Big* is an adjective. *Much* is not. You can say "he is big" but not "he is much".

*Enough* modifies adjectives (or verbs). It's an adverb (or a [determiner](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/nouns/what/what-is-a-determiner.html)). So "he is big enough" or "he is rich enough" or "he has studied enough", but there must be a verb or an adjective for it to make sense.

*Much* is also an adverb/determiner, just like *enough*. You can often use *much* in the same places you would use *enough*.

> Did it hurt much?
>
> Did it hurt enough?
>
> Has he got much money?
>
> Has he got enough money?

The correct version of "It's much enough" is "It's enough."

Comment: Thank you, this clarified so much

Comment: +DJClayworth how come dictionaries say much is an adjective and give examples for "too much cake" or "it's too much"

Comment: My dictionaries don't say it is an adjective. They call it a determiner, which means it modifies a noun but only in a limited sense relating to quantity.